# When is it appropriate to forego mathematical induction?

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I am well-acquainted with the use of mathematical induction in proofs, and I think I can usually tell when it's better to use one technique of proof over another. But up until now, the only way I've approached statements of the form "$\forall n\in\Bbb N: P(n)$" was using mathematical induction. I was taught that mathematical induction is a very useful tool, but recently I've encountered statements that seem like they could be proved much more easily without it. The problem got me thinking about this is the following:

"If $S$ is an ordered set with the least upper bound property, then any finite subset of $S$ has a supremum in $S$."

To prove it by induction, we could start with a subset $A \subseteq S$, with $A = \{x, y\}$, for some $x, y \in S$. By choosing $\alpha = max(x, y)$, we see that $\alpha$ is the supremum of $A$. Now, if we  suppose that all such subsets $A_n$ have suprema given by $\alpha_n = max(\{x: x \in A_n \})$, then we can show that the proposition is still true for subsets of size $n+1$.

My only issue is that it seems like we could do this whole process directly. Without going through the induction machinery, couldn't we, right from the beginning, say something like "let $A_{n+1}\subseteq S$, such that $|A_{n+1}| = n+1$, and choose $\alpha_{n+1} = max(\{x:x \in A_{n+1} \})$," and show directly that $\alpha_{n+1}$ satisfies the properties of a supremum? In doing so, we would be able to prove the statement above without using induction, even though it's a "$\forall n\in \Bbb N$" statement.

Comment: Yes, provided you've already proved that a nonempty finite subset of an ordered set has a maximum. How did you prove that? With or without induction?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I didn't prove it. I took it for granted - at the start of Rudin's textbook, he says that we assume familiarity with the integers, rationals, etc, but I forgot that proving that statement for an arbitrary ordered set is different from the case of the naturals and integers. But if  I were to prove it, would I be able to prove this without induction?

Comment: Beats me. I'm not a logician and not all that into rigor. If I know something is true, I don't see a lot to be gained by proving it.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: By the way, isn't the "least upper bound property" the one which says that every nonempty set which is bounded above has a least upper bound? So the real line, which has no least element, has the least upper bound property; and the empty set, which is finite, has no supremum in $\mathbb R$. So I guess you meant to say that every **nonempty** finite set has a supremum?

Comment: I did mean to say that, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, in case of finite subsets of ordered set, maximum and suprimum have the same meaning.
Here your statement must be:
"If S is an ordered set with the least upper bound property, then any finite subset A of S has a supremum in A."
You've assumed $|A| = n+1$ and $ max (A) = \alpha $. This means you are assuming the result for finite sets without proving it.

Comment: I think my wording may have made it unclear. I understand that if I were to do it by induction, then part of the inductive hypothesis would be that it works for finite sets. We can show that the result is true when $A$ has two elements - then part of the inductive hypothesis will be that we suppose the statement is true when $A$ has "n" elements. So if we suppose that $A$ has "n+1" elements, then we can take away any one of them, and the result will be a set with "n" elements, from which we apply the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: @kirafa, yes you're right

Comment: So with that being said, am I fine with proving this without induction? Since regardless, I could say "let $A$ be a finite subset of $S$, with size 'n'." And from there, if I were to define $\alpha = max(A)$, then I could show (by definition of max) that $\alpha$ is the supremum of A? (I get that it's probably more straightforward and makes more sense to use induction, but I'm just using this example in the context of asking a question about whether induction is strictly NEEDED in these kinds of proofs)

Comment: Mathematics yet has no way other than "Principle of Mathematical Induction" to prove such results. So, yes! One must use an induction to prove this.